# singular Probability -- help my understanding please

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am not sure if I understand correctly, in the textbook I use, singular distribution is defined as

A probability $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is $singular$ if there exists a Lebesgue null set $A$ such that $F_P'(t)$ exsits and is zero for all $t\notin A$

The text also mentions that all discrete probability is singular. However, Consider Bernoulli Distribution with $p=0.5$. Then, $P(0)=0.5,P(1)=0.5$. Define $A=\{0.3\}$, then by definition $F'_P(0)$ and $F'_P(1)$ must be equal to $0$, but we know that they are not.

I think I fail to understand the definition. How should I interpret the definition of singular probability?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the text says ".. if there exists a set $A$ whose Lebesgue measure is zero and is such that for all $t\notin A$, $F_{P}'(t)$ exists and equals zero". This does not mean that given an arbitrary measurable set $A$ of Lebesgue measure zero, if $F_{P}'(t)$ does not exist or exists and is not equal to zero for at least some $t\notin A$, then the measure is not singular. This last statement is what you have experimented with.

You have considered $A=\{0.3\}$ and argued on the lines of contradiction by considering $F_{P}'(0)$ and $F_{P}'(1)$. First, kindly note that $F_{P}(t)$ is not continuous at both $t=0$ and $t=1$, and hence, $F_{P}'(0)$ and $F_{P}'(1)$ do not exist. Second, as I pointed out in the previous paragraph, an arbitrary choice of the set $A$ need not satisfy the condition mentioned for singularity. In fact, for the problem at hand, $A=\{0,1\}$. Notice that for any $t\notin \{0,1\}$, $F_{P}'(t)$ exists and equals zero.